# Как правильно организовать хранение временных файлов (изображений)

Tags: javascript, php, html

Как организовать хранение изображений в базе данных, для ситуации когда:

- Пользователь переходит на страницу создания поста - загружает картинки Ajax методом, загруженные картинки сразу же отображаются через тот же Ajax (чтобы он мог контролировать загружаемый контент). Есть поле для ввода текста, и кнопка подтверждения создания поста.

Вопрос: Как организовать правильное хранение (временных) загруженных файлов (изображений) не прикрепляя их к определенному посту (потому что он еще не создан т.к не заполнен текст и не нажата кнопка создать). А после заполнения всей формы временные файлы которые загрузил пользователь подтягивались бы к созданному посту .
Пользователь может же отказаться от дальнейшего заполнения формы (текста) после загрузки изображений и простой уйти со страницы, а изображения тогда будут просто висеть в базе.

Comment: Откуда картинки "загружаются Ajax методом"?

Comment: Ну храни во временной папке, при создании поста переноси из нее в рабочую папку. Временную папку время от времени зачищай.